# System.lineSeparator() returns nothing

Tags: java, newline, linefeed

What should I see when I use the following?

```
System.out.println("LineSeperator1: "+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println("LineSeperator2: "+System.lineSeparator());
```

I get the following back:

```
LineSeperator1: 

LineSeperator2:
```

Is it empty? invisible? shouldn there be something like `\r  or \n`?

I use windows 7, eclipse and jdk 1.8.

Comment: It has added a new line. It doesn't show the escape character. Instead it does its behavior

Comment: `\n` is a newline, you don't expect to see a newline ?

Comment: Good advise for printing potentially invisible things: print something visible closely around, like println("thingy is: <" + whatever + ">");

Comment: @Jägermeister +1 Indeed. Alternatively inspect the value using the debugger. This will reveal the actual byte array.

Comment: Ok thx. I wanted to replace all lineSeparators, therefore I need to know how does the lineSeparator look like in that specific environment. Is it \n or \r or \r\n...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you expect, the line separator contains special characters such as `'\r'` or `'\n'` that denote the end of a line. However, although they would be written in Java source code with those backslash escape sequences, they do not appear that way when printed. The purpose of a line separator is to separate lines, so, for example, the output of

```
System.out.println("Hello"+System.lineSeparator()+"World");
```

is

```
Hello
World
```

rather than, say

```
Hello\nWorld
```

You can even see this in the output of your code: the output of

```
System.out.println("LineSeperator1: "+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

had an extra blank line before the output of the next statement, because there was a line separator from `System.getProperty("line.separator")` and another from the use of `println`.

---

If you really want to see what the escaped versions of the line separators look like, you can use [`escapeJava`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi). For example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class LineSeparators {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ls1 = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        System.out.println("LineSeperator1: "+ls1);
        String ls2 = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(System.lineSeparator());
        System.out.println("LineSeperator2: "+ls2);
    }
}
```

On my system, this outputs

```
LineSeparator1: \n
LineSeparator2: \n
```

Note that I had to run it in the same folder as the .jar file from [the Apache download](http://apache.claz.org//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.4-bin.zip), compiling and running with these commands

```
javac -cp commons-lang3-3.4.jar LineSeparators.java
java -cp commons-lang3-3.4.jar:. LineSeparators
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing something afterwards will show the effect:

```
System.out.println("a" + System.lineSeparator() + "b");
```

Gives

```
a
b
```