# Weird behavior of appending Strings

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I am using the following code to generate a text dump of an object:

```
public static String generateText(Quiz quiz){
    String endResult = "";
    for (QuizQuestion question : quiz.getQuestions()) {
        endResult += question.getQuestion();
        endResult += System.lineSeparator();
        endResult += question.getAnswer1();
        endResult += System.lineSeparator();
        endResult += question.getAnswer2();
        endResult += System.lineSeparator();
        endResult += question.getAnswer3();
        endResult += System.lineSeparator();
        endResult += question.getAnswer4();
        endResult += System.lineSeparator();
        endResult += question.getCorrectAnswer();
        endResult += System.lineSeparator();
    }

    return endResult;
}
```

However when I print `endResult` to a file tis is the output:

```
questiona1a2a3a4a
```

Then it prints 4 empty lines. How can this be fixed?

Comment: why don't you override the `toString()` method instead? You can use that to make a text representation of all the fields and values within the object.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you hard-code the results of `question` method calls?

Comment: If I hard-code the results the newlines appear as normal.

Comment: I just tried to add QuizQuestion code but when I click SaveEdit button on Edit page it doesn't work

Comment: Then you need to provide the code of your question object, the code you use to call this method and the code you use to print the result. Basically, a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984415/system-lineseparator-returns-nothing

Comment: @nabeel. How is that related?

Comment: It's not. The newlines are printed (empty lines) just in the wrong location